# How to detect if 32 or 64 bit JDK is installed?

Tags: 12.04, jdk

How can I detect if 32bit or 64bit Java JDK (SDK) has been installed on my machine? I am running a 64bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
java -version
```

For 64-bit, you'll see `64-bit Server VM` instead of `Client VM`.  See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run the commands: `java -d64 -version` or `java -d32 -version` and you will get an error for the version that is not supported.

[image]